# How to select rows with no matching entry in another table?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I'm doing some maintenance work on a database application and I've discovered that, joy of joys, even though values from one table are being used in the style of foreign keys, there's no foreign key constraints on the tables.

I'm trying to add FK constraints on these columns, but I'm finding that, because there's already a whole load of bad data in the tables from previous errors which have been naively corrected, I need to find the rows which don't match up to the other table and then delete them.

I've found some examples of this kind of query on the web, but they all seem to provide examples rather than explanations, and I don't understand why they work.

Can someone explain to me how to construct a query which returns all the rows with no matches in another table, and what it's doing, so that I can make these queries myself, rather than coming running to SO for every table in this *mess* that has no FK constraints?

Answer (score 857, accepted):

Here's a simple query:

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

The key points are:

1. `LEFT JOIN` is used; this will return ALL rows from `Table1`, regardless of whether or not there is a matching row in `Table2`.
2. The `WHERE t2.ID IS NULL` clause; this will restrict the results returned to only those rows where the ID returned from `Table2` is null - in other words there is **NO** record in `Table2` for that particular ID from `Table1`. `Table2.ID` will be returned as NULL for all records from `Table1` where the ID is not matched in `Table2`.

Comment: Fails if an ID is NULL

Comment: @Michael - If having a `NULL` ID is valid in your schema, you might have bigger problems, wouldn't you agree? :)

Comment: will this work even if table1 has more records then table2? if table1 has 100 records and table2 has 200 records (100 that match/join and 100 that don't match/join) would we get all 200 records returned?

Comment: I often like to wrap the left join as a subquery/inline view in order to ensure there is no interplay between the WHERE clause and the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: This is much slower than `exists` when there's more than one row in Table2 for each row in Table 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36694478/37923 is a better answer

Comment: I find it very strange that we first say: `t1.ID = t2.ID` which means both id in both tables should be equal and then we say oh but the id on the other table should be null `t2.ID IS NULL` doesn't that second statement means that t1.ID != t2.ID which is contradictory to the first statement?

Comment: @jas t1.ID = t2.ID is the join. t2.ID is Null is the filter.

Comment: @Jas Key point 1 of the answer, ALL rows from first table, even those not matching t1.ID = t2.ID condition of left join.
If you change first line to `SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID` and remove WHERE line you will get better idea how this works.

Answer (score 200):

I would use [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) expression since it is more powerful, you can e.g. more precisely choose rows you would like to join. In the case of `LEFT JOIN`, you have to take everything that's in the joined table. Its efficiency is probably the same as in the case of `LEFT JOIN` with null constraint.

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.ID FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID)
```

Comment: Something this simple is easily handled by the query optimizer for best execution.

Comment: Yes, main advantage of `EXISTS` is its variability.

Comment: is it supposed to work in mysql ? I keep getting 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: It shoudl work for MySQL see docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Actually reduced the speed of one query i had from 7 sec to 200ms... (compared to `WHERE t2.id IS NULL` )
Thank You.

Comment: @MotiKorets you mean increased the speed :)

Comment: The other advantage of this method is if working in phpMyAdmin, it potentially gives a unique key to the line so you get the Edit, Copy, Delete options in the visual interface as opposed to using a join where you may not get those options.

Comment: **AWESOME!!!** with SQL Server, this is a lot faster than `WHERE t2.ID is NULL`.   So I guess the optimizer failed to recognize this.  This seems to happen to me a lot.  Trivial changes to the query have huge impact on performance.  As if the optimizer doesn't do shit.

Comment: **This should be the accepted answer.** A `NOT EXISTS()` will generally have better performance over a `LEFT JOIN` as mentioned above. See the execution plans in [this db<>query](https://dbfiddle.uk/JTp9N9hN).  A `NOT EXISTS()` also clearly shows the intent.  The `WHERE ID NOT IN (...)` approach also has good performance.

Answer (score 24):

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE foreign_key_id_column NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

Table 1 has a column that you want to add the foreign key constraint to, but the values in the `foreign_key_id_column` don't all match up with an `id` in table 2.

1. The initial select lists the `id`s from table1. These will be the rows we want to delete.
2. The `NOT IN` clause in the where statement limits the query to only rows where the value in the `foreign_key_id_column` is not in the list of table 2 `id`s.
3. The `SELECT` statement in parenthesis will get a list of all the `id`s that are in table 2.

Comment: @zb226: Your link to has to do with limits on the `IN` clause with a list of literal values.  It doesn't apply to using an `IN` clause with the result of a sub-query.  That accepted answer to that question actually solves the problem by using a sub-query.

(A large list of literal values is problematic because it creates a huge SQL expression.  A sub-query works fine because, even if the resulting list is large, the SQL expression itself is small.)

Comment: Not a good option to use. Imagine if you are querying on huge data. let's say, a million of rows fetched and included in the subquery and compiler again has to match each row against all the ids returned in subquery. A big no from my side.

Comment: Worth noting that if column in the subquery is `NULL`able this query could likely yield no results, as `NOT IN (<List where at least one value resolves to NULL>)` results in UNKNOWN.

Answer (score 13):

Let we have the following 2 tables(salary and employee)
[image]

**Now i want those records from employee table which are not in salary.**
We can do this in 3 ways:

1. **Using inner Join**

```
select * from employee
where id not in(select e.id from employee e inner join salary s on e.id=s.id)
```

[image]

2. **Using Left outer join**

```
select * from employee e 
left outer join salary s on e.id=s.id  where s.id is null
```

[image]

3. **Using Full Join**

```
select * from employee e
full outer join salary s on e.id=s.id where e.id not in(select id from salary)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Where `T2` is the table to which you're adding the constraint:

```
SELECT *
FROM T2
WHERE constrained_field NOT
IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.constrained_field
    FROM T2 
    INNER JOIN T1 t
    USING ( constrained_field )
)
```

And delete the results.

Answer (score 4):

From similar question here [MySQL Inner Join Query To Get Records Not Present in Other Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954749/mysql-inner-join-query-to-get-records-not-present-in-other-table) I got this to work

```
SELECT * FROM bigtable 
LEFT JOIN smalltable ON bigtable.id = smalltable.id 
WHERE smalltable.id IS NULL
```

`smalltable` is where you have missing records, `bigtable` is where you have all the records. The query list all the records that not exist in `smalltable` but exists on the `bigtable`. You could replace `id` by any other matching criteria.

Answer (score 2):

I Dont Knew Which one Is Optimized (compared to @AdaTheDev
) but This one seems to be quicker when I use (atleast for me)

```sql
SELECT id  FROM  table_1 EXCEPT SELECT DISTINCT (table1_id) table1_id FROM table_2
```

If You want to get any other specific attribute you can use:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 where id in (SELECT id  FROM  table_1 EXCEPT SELECT DISTINCT (table1_id) table1_id FROM table_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could opt for **Views** as shown below:

```
CREATE VIEW AuthorizedUserProjectView AS select t1.username as username, t1.email as useremail, p.id as projectid, 
(select m.role from userproject m where m.projectid = p.id and m.userid = t1.id) as role 
FROM authorizeduser as t1, project as p
```

and then work on the view for selecting or updating:

```
select * from AuthorizedUserProjectView where projectid = 49
```

which yields the result as shown in the picture below i.e. for non-matching column null has been filled in.

```
[Result of select on the view][1]
```

Answer (score -2):

**You can do something like this**

```
   SELECT IFNULL(`price`.`fPrice`,100) as fPrice,product.ProductId,ProductName 
          FROM `products` left join `price` ON 
          price.ProductId=product.ProductId AND (GeoFancingId=1 OR GeoFancingId 
          IS NULL) WHERE Status="Active" AND Delete="No"
```

Answer (score -4):

SELECT * FROM First_table 
MINUS
SELECT * FROM another

Answer (score -6):

How to select rows with no matching entry in Both table?

```
    select * from [dbo].[EmppDetails] e
     right join [Employee].[Gender] d on e.Gid=d.Gid
    where e.Gid is Null

    union 
    select * from [dbo].[EmppDetails] e
     left join [Employee].[Gender] d on e.Gid=d.Gid
    where d.Gid is Null
```