# How to change this query to use joins (inner or left) but not subquery to get same result

Tags: sql-server

How to change this query to use joins (inner or left) but not subquery

```
 SELECT * FROM   External_Blk_Itm_Contracts ELC
    WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT
                    NULL
                FROM        
                    [BUDCONTRACTS] c
                INNER JOIN 
                    BUDTERMINALS t on t.TerminalID = c.TerminalID  AND  t.MBFTERMINALNAME = ELC.TerminalName AND  c.CONTRACTNAME = ELC.ContractName 
                INNER JOIN 
                    BudCustomers ct on ct.CustomerId = c.CustomerId AND ELC.CustomerName = ct.LegalName
               )
                AND ELC.ContractName = '00-000'
```

Comment: I think it should perform better as it is, left joins will make it less efficient **ITHINK**

Comment: What is the schema of the tables involved?  In particular the primary keys and foreign key columns?  Could you post an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: I want the same query to be with joins without subquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select rows with no matching entry in another table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076098/how-to-select-rows-with-no-matching-entry-in-another-table)

Comment: @TabAlleman Not duplicate

Comment: The answer in the duplicate can be adapted to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Untested (obviously):

```
SELECT distinct
  ELC.* 
FROM
  External_Blk_Itm_Contracts ELC
LEFT JOIN  
  BUDCONTRACTS c on c.CONTRACTNAME = ELC.ContractName
LEFT JOIN 
  BUDTERMINALS t on t.TerminalID = c.TerminalID and t.MBFTERMINALNAME = ELC.TerminalName
LEFT JOIN 
  BudCustomers ct on ct.CustomerId = c.CustomerId and ELC.CustomerName = ct.LegalName
WHERE   
  c.CONTRACTNAME is NULL 
  and t.TerminalID is NULL
  and ct.CustomerID is NULL
  AND ELC.ContractName = '00-000'
```

My biggest question about this is why we're joining using name fields to ELC? Isn't there e.g. TerminalID, CustomerID and CotractID available on ELC?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by

```
        SELECT ELC.* FROM External_Blk_Itm_Contracts ELC
        INNER JOIN BUDTERMINALS BT ON BT.MBFTERMINALNAME = ELC.TerminalName AND ELC.ContractName = '00-000' 
        INNER JOIN BudCustomers BCUST ON BCUST.LegalName = ELC.CustomerName
        LEFT JOIN BUDCONTRACTS BCON ON BCON.CONTRACTNAME = ELC.ContractName AND BCON.TERMINALID = BT.TERMINALID AND BCON.CUSTOMERID = BCUST.CustomerID  
        WHERE    BCON.CONTRACTID IS NULL
```