# Selecting row from two table

Tags: php, sql

please can anyone help me, I am familiar with PHP but I'm not good in it.please help. I have two table and both have `id`, see sample,

**Table1**

```
----------------------------------
   **ID**   |   **NAME**     |   **AGE**    |
----------------------------------
  001   |   john     |    21     |
----------------------------------
  002   |   erik     |    18     |
----------------------------------
  003   |   ella     |    19     |
----------------------------------
and soon...
```

**Table2**

```
----------------------------------
   **ID**   |   **SUBJECT**     |   **GRADE**    |
----------------------------------
  001   |   math     |    80     |
----------------------------------
  003   |   english     |    83     |
----------------------------------
and soon....
```

here is the problem, I just want to select a row from table1 were its `id` dont match in table2.

I used this condition but it wont work the way I expected to so that means this is wrong,

```
if($t1_id!=$t2_id){
blah blah blah...
}
else
{
all data is match!
}
```

when an `id` in table2 matched in table1 it already show that my `data is all match` even if there is only one entry in table2.

Please help me. If you don,t understand how I show my problem please tell me,THANK YOU!.

Comment: try this as your query : `select * from table1,table2 where table1.id=table2.id` , this query only find  users  that have grade

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar your solution will only find matches(that is not what is being asked for). You are using a method which is more than 20 years old to join your tables

Comment: @t-clausen.dk you right , yeah its 20 years old , better practice was `join` only want to check what he exactly want :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select rows with no matching entry in another table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076098/how-to-select-rows-with-no-matching-entry-in-another-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 solutions will work in sqlserver:

Solution 1:

```
SELECT
  t1.ID, t1.NAME, t1.AGE
FROM
  table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
  table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.ID is null
```

Solution 2:

```
SELECT
  ID, NAME, AGE
FROM
  table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE t1.ID = ID)
```

Comment: this is great! Thank you sir t-clausen.dk! solution 2 works great!..thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` clause to check whether a record is present in another table, e.g.

```
select * 
from table1 t1
where t1.id = ?
and exists(
 select * 
 from table2 t2 
 where t2.id = t1.id;
);
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he meant.

Comment: I've got the solution to  my problem..thank you also for the help.