# How to get scope with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building a Rails 5 app and in this app I got two models.
First one is called Timeoff and second one is called Approval.

I want to get all Timeoff objects that got no approvals.

**The time off model**

```
class Timeoff < ApplicationRecord

  scope :not_approved, -> { self.approvals.size > 0 }

  has_many :approvals, as: :approvable, dependent: :destroy

end
```

**The Approval model**

```
class Approval < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :approvable, polymorphic: true

end
```

**I am calling it like this**

```
Timeoff.not_approved
```

**I get the error**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `approvals' for #<Class:0x007f9698587830>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call `approvals` in the class context, but it actually belongs to an instance of `Timeoff`. For example:

```
Timeoff.approvals # doesn't work
Timeoff.first.approvals # works
```

That's why you get the `undefined method` error.
But I think you want a database query here. You could go two ways - that I know of:

Make two queries: find the `timeoffs` that have `approvals` and then query for the other ones using `NOT IN`

```
timeoff_ids = Approval.where(approvable_type: 'Timeoff').pluck(:approvable_id)
Timeoff.where.not(id: timeoff_ids)
```

This may get really slow if your tables are big.
Or you could do a join on the `approvals` table and filter to where the id is null:

```
Timeoff.joins("LEFT JOIN approvals ON timeoffs.id = approvals.approvable_id AND approvals.approvable_type = 'Timeoff'").where("approvals.id IS NULL")
```

This should also work, and may be faster - but you should measure with your own data to be sure.

Also, take a look at this question: [How to select rows with no matching entry in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076098/how-to-select-rows-with-no-matching-entry-in-another-table) there is a complete explanation of the second query and some other ways to solve it.