# SQL statement to compare two queries and only pull records not entered

Tags: sql, ms-access

EDITED: Please look again.

```
`qryHistoryTimeLog`   /   `qryHistoryAppt`
34 , 03/07/17 , 170   /   34 , 01/13/17 , Checked Out and Complete
34 , 03/28/17 , 125   /   34 , 02/09/17 , Checked Out and Complete
34 , 04/28/17 , 140   /   34 , 03/07/17 , Checked Out and Complete
34 , 05/19/17 ,  85   /   34 , 03/28/17 , Checked Out and Complete
34 , 08/05/17 ,  75   /   34 , 04/28/17 , Checked Out and Complete
34 , 08/24/17 ,  65   /   34 , 05/19/17 , Checked Out and Complete
                      /   34 , 06/09/17 , Checked Out and Complete
                      /   34 , 08/05/17 , Checked Out and Complete
                      /   34 , 08/24/17 , Checked Out and Complete
```

The query `qryHistoryAppt` is pulling from the software's database table of all appointments that are for client #34 and are "Checked Out and Complete".

The query `qryHistoryTimeLog` is pulling from my table of entered information from the client's appointment.

I am looking for the appointment dates that have been Checked Out and Completed, but have not yet been entered into my `tblTimeLog` so I know which appointment cards need to be pulled and entered.

```
`qryTesting`
34 , 01/13/17
34 , 02/09/17
34 , 06/09/17
```

I also should add, that I am passing along the client number through this new query. So that when I run the query I can enter which client's appointments I am looking for.

ANSWERED:

```
SELECT DISTINCT qryHistoryAppt.petId, 
                qryHistoryAppt.petName, 
                qryHistoryAppt.cstLName, 
                qryHistoryAppt.aptDate
FROM qryHistoryAppt LEFT JOIN qryHistoryTimeLog ON 
    (qryHistoryAppt.petId = qryHistoryTimeLog.PetID) AND 
    (qryHistoryAppt.aptDate = qryHistoryTimeLog.ApptDate)
WHERE (((qryHistoryAppt.petId)=[]) AND
       ((qryHistoryTimeLog.ApptDate) Is Null));
```

Comment: Change it to a `LEFT JOIN` and then `Where [qryHistoryTimeLog].[ApptDate] IS NULL` Remove the `Group By` and `Having`

Comment: Not looking for a null. Comparing what dates from the software side are not entered into the tblTimeLog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select rows with no matching entry in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076098/how-to-select-rows-with-no-matching-entry-in-another-table)

Comment: @WEI_DBA, could you look again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `LEFT JOIN` on *petId* **and** *ApptDate*. Right now you are only matching against *petID*.

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.petId, h.aptDate
FROM qryHistoryAppt h
LEFT JOIN qryHistoryTimeLog l 
   ON h.petId = l.PetID AND h.aptDate = l.ApptDate
WHERE (((l.PetID) IS NULL));
```

Comment: Awesome!! Kudos!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT qryHistoryAppt.petId, 
         qryHistoryAppt.petName, 
         qryHistoryAppt.aptDate
FROM qryHistoryAppt LEFT JOIN qryHistoryTimeLog ON qryHistoryAppt.petId = qryHistoryTimeLog.PetID
WHERE qryHistoryTimeLog.PetID is null
GROUP BY qryHistoryAppt.petId, qryHistoryAppt.petName, qryHistoryAppt.aptDate
HAVING (((qryHistoryAppt.petId)=[]))
ORDER BY qryHistoryAppt.aptDate DESC;
```

Comment: The Where statement is still not working right. All of the dates from the software side are not entered into the tblTimeLog. All I want to see are the dates that are missing from that table.

Comment: could you take a new look at this