# How to retrieve only those rows of a table (db1) which are not in another table (db2)

Tags: sql

I have a table `t1` in db1, and another table `t2` in `db2`. I have the same columns in both tables.

How do I retrieve only those rows which are not in the other table?

```
select id_num 
from [db1].[dbo].[Tbl1]

except 

select id_num
from [db2].[dbo].[Tb01]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076098/how-to-select-rows-with-no-matching-entry-in-another-table

Comment: You could consider creating database like between these two database and then use the approach mentioned in the reference pasted by "Harshit kyal".

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: for just id_num it would be... select ID_NUM from a exception join b on a.id_num = b.idnum ... for all columns I have answer below.  Maybe its a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT JOIN or WHERE NOT IN functions.

Using WHERE NOT IN:

`select 
    dbase1.id_num from [db1].[dbo].[Tbl1] as dbase1 
    where dbase1.id_num not in 
    (select dbase2.id_num from [db2].[dbo].[Tb01] as dbase2)`

Using LEFT JOIN (recommended as this is much faster)

`SELECT dbase1.id_num
    FROM [db1].[dbo].[Tbl1] as dbase1
    LEFT JOIN [db2].[dbo].[Tb01] as dbase2 ON dbase2.id_num COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_A = dbase1.id_num  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_A
    WHERE dbase2.id_num IS NULL`

Comment: getting the error :Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: That error means that you're 2 databases are using different colaltions. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Try to use again the LEFT JOIN function

Answer (score 0):

Compare tables with DB2 other databases may have a select a - b statement or similar.  Because at the time my database also didn't have a-b I use the following.  Wrap the statement in a create table statement to dig into the results.  No rows and the tables are identical.  I've added in a column BEFORE|AFTER which makes the results easy to read.

```
SELECT 'AFTER', A.* FROM      
(SELECT * FROM &AFTER         
EXCEPT                        
 SELECT * FROM &BEFORE) AS A  
UNION                         
SELECT 'BEFORE', B.* FROM     
(SELECT * FROM &BEFORE        
EXCEPT                        
 SELECT * FROM &AFTER) AS B
```