# How to find difference in rows for two tables in DB2 or SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

In the table1 I have 1421144 rows and table2 has 1421134 rows.

I tried this query, but I don't get any rows returned.

```
select table1.ID 
from table1
where ID not in (select ID from table2)
```

I have also used this query:

```
select ID from table1
except
select ID from table2
```

But I don't get any rows. Please help me, if the table1 has duplicates how can I get those duplicates?

Comment: Is the ID column on both tables actually a unique key? Or can you have two records with Id=1, for example?

Comment: SELECT T1.ID FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id WHERE T2.Id IS NULL   -- This will get you all records in T1 that dont exist in T2, assuming the answer to my first question is "yes"

Comment: Yes the ID's in the two tables are same and unique. In fact all the columns in both the tables are same.

Comment: I have tried the above query and the result is 0 rows. @BenM

Comment: The only way that's possible is if there are duplicate records (with duplicate ID's). Try Gordon's second query in his answer, with the GROUP BY: 

select t1.id, count(*)
from t1
group by t1.id
having count(*) > 1;

Comment: Easy to find difference by table or fields. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066934/difference-between-data-values-in-two-db2-tables-with-different-table-structures/48068108#48068108

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ids are unique, you can use `full outer join` in either database:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
       (case when t1.id is null then 'T2 only' else 'T1 only' end) 
from t1 full outer join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id is null or t2.id is null;
```

It is quite possible that the two tables have the same sets of ids, but there are duplicates.  Try this:

```
select t1.id, count(*)
from t1
group by t1.id
having count(*) > 1;
```

and

```
select t2.id, count(*)
from t2
group by t2.id
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: When I try the above query 1 no rows are returned. But when I tried the above query 2 and 3. I got 10 rows difference again with 36687 rows in table 1 and 36677 rows in table2 @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicates, try:

```
WITH Dups AS(
    SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS DupCount
    FROM Table1)
SELECT *
FROM Dups
WHERE DupCount > 1;
```

If you need to delete the dups, you can use the following syntax:

```
WITH Dups AS(
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS DupCount
    FROM Table1)
DELETE FROM Dups
WHERE DupCount > 1;
```

Obviously, however, check the data before you run a `DELETE` statement you got from a random on the internet. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I Guess u have data type mismatch between 2 tables, cast them to integers and try your first query

```
select table1.ID from table1
where cast(ID as int) not in (select cast(ID as int) from table2)
```

If you have stored in a different format than `int`, cast them to `varchar` and 
 try with this datatype.

`Not in` takes longer to execute, use left join instead

```
select t1id from 
(
select t1.id t1Id, t2.Id t2Id from  table1 left join table2
on cast(t1.id as int) = cast(t2.id as int) 
) x where t2Id is null
```