# How to select all the values from a table except the values which are in foreign table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables:`tbl_borrower, tbl_client`and`tbl_guarantor`

```
tbl_Client:
    id|name|address|email|

tbl_Guarantor:
    id|clientid(fk)|Guaranteed_date|borrower_id(fk from borrower table)
```

I want to retrieve all the values of client table except the values which are present in guarantor table in the controller of `Laravel 5.5`.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the models and relationships set up, you should just do:

```
Client::doesntHave('guarantor')->get()
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the query builder, it would be:

```
 $clients = DB::table('tbl_clients')
        ->join('tbl_guarantor', 'tbl_clients.id', '=', 'tbl_guarantor.clientid')
        ->select('tbl_clients.*')
        ->whereNull('tbl_guarantor.clientid')
        ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

With the premise of using a left join and testing for NULL on the 2nd table id based on this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4076157/3585500

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DB::table('tbl_Client')
      ->groupBy('tbl_Client.id')                           
      ->leftjoin('tbl_Guarantor', 'tbl_Client.id', '=', 'tbl_Guarantor.clientid')                           
      ->get([
           'tbl_Client.*'
       ]);
```