# How to find a record that does not exists from a table based on other table value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, not-exists

So i have two tables, this one is `books`

[image: books]

and this one is `payment`

[image: payment]

now i want to select if there are any records in `books` that have a similiar(`select * from a like a.field like '%blabla%`) `title` or even the same `title` but not exist in `payment`

i tried not exist but im not sure because the executing query process is very long so i thought it wasn't the case.

Comment: What does "similar(like)" mean?

Comment: select * from a where a.field like '%blabla%'

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Even if *the executing query process is very long* this does not mean that the query is wrong. Post what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information, I have tried to put together an example. I hope this is helpful and gets you close to what you want.

```
CREATE TABLE books
    (`number` int, `verification_date` date, `title` varchar(6))
;
    
INSERT INTO books
    (`number`, `verification_date`, `title`)
VALUES
    (14116299, '2020-05-01 18:00:00', 'Title1'),
    (12331189, '2020-07-01 18:00:00', 'Title2'),
    (13123321, NULL, 'Title4'),
    (12318283, '2020-12-31 18:00:00', 'Title3'),
    (12318284, '2021-01-31 18:00:00', 'Title2')
;



CREATE TABLE payments
    (`number` int, `title` varchar(6), `pay_date` date)
;
    
INSERT INTO payments
    (`number`, `title`, `pay_date`)
VALUES
    (14116299, 'Title1', '2020-05-01 18:00:00'),
    (12318283, 'Title3', '2020-12-31 17:00:00')
;
```

We are selecting all columns from books and keeping only records that don't have a match in the payments table. More info on this: [How to select rows with no matching entry in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076098/how-to-select-rows-with-no-matching-entry-in-another-table). Then added an additional where clause to search the books table for titles.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM books b
LEFT JOIN payments p ON b.number = p.number
WHERE p.number is NULL
    AND b.title LIKE'%2'
```

Output:

```
number  verification_date   title
12331189    2020-07-01      Title2
12318284    2021-01-31      Title2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e13254/10)