# How to find the records which has non existing foreign key?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys, subquery

I need to find the products which has invalid foreign key assigned.

Note :

- Company has many products
- Company has many categories
- Products has one category (foreign key = category_id)

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE category_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM categories);
```

will not help me because a company level check is required. Ie,

- Company A

  - has Categories c1, c2
  - has Product P1 belongs to c3 (invalid), Product P2 belongs to c1 (valid)
- Company B

  - has category c1,c2, c3

So in the above scenario I need to find Product P1 which refers to category c3 which is not available at p1's company (Company A).

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076098/how-to-select-rows-with-no-matching-entry-in-another-table although there are more likely better Rails specific dup targets.

Comment: @CrazyCat . . . You don't even show the foreign key (or intended foreign key) definition.  The question is quite unclear.

Comment: category_id is the foreign_key to category table @GordonLinoff

Comment: You can do an OUTER JOIN and look for null values in the join field.

Comment: Without the schema for the tables involved this is not going to get you a solid answer. For one there is no indication of how to determine what are legitimate categories for a company.

Comment: If `category_id` is foreign key then it's not possible to have non-matching values with it. The engine won't allow them. The question doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: @TheImpaler in Rails its unfortunely quite common that devs incorrectly refer to any column containing references to another table as a  "foreign key" no matter if there is a foreign key constraint or not actually linking them. Its partly ActiveRecord's fault as it plays loose and fast with the terminology.

Comment: @max Thanks for the clarification. I'll keep it in mind.