# Select where no entry in related table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a better way to select entries in a table which are *not* referenced in another table?

Currently I `LEFT JOIN` the other table, and filter where the other table's primary key is null:

```sql
SELECT TableA.*
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.id = TableB.TableA_fk
WHERE TableB.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Define "better". What is your criteria for a different method being "better"?

Comment: Better = idiomatic for someone who's not built up their SQL and SQL Server skills by random accretion ;)

Comment: This is called an **exclusion join**, and it is an accepted and reasonable way to complete the task.

However, a `NOT EXISTS()` operation can also work, and I'd _generally_ (always test if it matters) expect it to run faster.

Comment: For best performance, I recommend that you ensure that you have an index on TableB(TableA_fk). That will support both regular joins to that table and the above check for no matching record.

Comment: The execution plans shown in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jQWj-auk) seems to show that a `NOT EXISTS()` condition is better optimized under certain conditions over the `LEFT JOIN` approach. I would have thought that SQL server would recognize the `LEFT JOIN` together with either `WHERE PK_column IS NULL` or `WHERE JoinedColumn IS NULL` as being a pattern equivalent to `NOT EXISTS()`, using a "left anti semi join" for both. However, it seems that this is not the case.

Comment: NOTE: **The accepted answer** in the linked "already has answers here" question **is less efficient** than the [second top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076098/how-to-select-rows-with-no-matching-entry-in-another-table/36694478#36694478).